# Postgresql: Can the minus operator not be used with a parameter? Only hardcoded values?

Tags: postgresql, parameters, node-postgres

The following query deletes an entry using index:

```
 const deleteGameQuery = ` 
                update users 
                set games = games - 1
                where username = $1
            `
```

If I pass the index as a parameter, nothing is deleted:

```
const gameIndex = rowsCopy[0].games.findIndex(obj => obj.game == gameID).toString();


            const deleteGameQuery = ` 
                update users 
                set games = games - $1
                where username = $2
            `
    
          const { rows } = await query(deleteGameQuery, [gameIndex, username]);

          ctx.body = rows;
```

The gameIndex parameter is just a string, the same as if I typed it. So why doesn't it seem to read the value? Is this not allowed?

The column games is a jsonb data type with the following data:

```
[
    {
        "game": "cyberpunk-2077",
        "status": "Backlog",
        "platform": "Any"
    },
    {
        "game": "new-pokemon-snap",
        "status": "Backlog",
        "platform": "Any"
    }
]
```

Comment: What is the result of the query? The statement looks good so either $1==0 or $2 does not contain the exact user name. If rows==0 it means that $2 is not present in table. If rows>0 it mean that $1==0.

Comment: @Vicctor Result is []. I even hard code the parameter to "1" and still the same. You can see from screenshot [here](https://i.imgur.com/DDRBkMh.png) they are in the database.

Comment: @Schwern The first query in post does delete object inside array using index number given, I tested it.

Comment: @George That's the important part: what's in games. If you make that clear in your post you'll get an answer.

Comment: @Schwern Check the screenshot I just posted in first comment.

Comment: @George If you edit the information into your post as text, you will get better answers. `set games = games - 1` will remove the ***second*** element from the array. Is this what you want? `[1,2,3] - 1` is `[1,3]`.

Comment: @Schwern Edited, thanks. Yeah it deletes via index which is great but I want to be able to pass index as parameter as won't be the same index each time, see second code block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're passing text instead of an integer. You need to pass an integer. I'm not sure exactly how your database interface works to pass integers, try removing `toString()` and ensure `gameIndex` is a [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

`const gameIndex = rowsCopy[0].games.findIndex(obj => obj.game == gameID)`.

---

`array - integer` and `array - text` mean two different things.

`array - 1` removes the ***second*** element from the array.

```
select '[1,2,3]'::jsonb - 1;

 [1, 3]
```

`array - '1'` searches for the entry `'1'` and removes it.

```
select '["1","2","3"]'::jsonb - '1';

 ["2", "3"]

-- Here, nothing is removed because 1 != '1'.
select '[1,2,3]'::jsonb - '1';

 [1, 2, 3]
```

When you pass in a parameter, it is translated by `query` according to its type. If you pass a Number it will be translated as `1`. If you pass a String it will be translated as `'1'`. (Or at least that's how it should work, I'm not totally familiar with Javascript database libraries.)

---

As a side note, this sort of data is better handled as a [join table](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
create table games (
  id bigserial primary key,
  name text not null,
  status text not null,
  platform text not null
);

create table users (
  id bigserial primary key,
  username text not null
);

create table game_users (
  game_id bigint not null references games,
  user_id bigint not null references users,

  -- If a user can only have each game once.
  unique(game_id, user_id)
);

-- User 1 has games 1 and 2. User 2 has game 2.
insert into game_users (game_id, user_id) values (1, 1), (2, 1), (2,2);

-- User 1 no longer has game 1.
delete from game_users where game_id = 1 and user_id = 1;
```

You would also have a platforms table and a game_platforms join table.

Join tables are a little mind bending, but they're how SQL stores relationships. JSONB is very useful, but it is not a substitute for relationships.

Comment: So I tried the passing number before as well and that didn't work unfortunatly e.g.  `await query(deleteGameQuery, [1, username]);`. I will look into join table as I haven't heard of them before.

Comment: @George Just to be sure, try hard coding the username as well. Are you using [`node-postgres`](https://node-postgres.com/)? I'm not sure exactly how that works, just the Postgres side. I've tagged your question to get proper attention for the node interface.

Comment: @George And check the [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) of `gameIndex`. You might have to convert it to Numeric or even BigInt.

Comment: Yes but the code I'm using is minimal, the query function is just this: `const query = (text: string, params: any) => {
  return dbConfig.query(text, params)
}`

Comment: I have tried hardcoding username too, and converting index to Int and BigNumber.

Comment: Got it working. I had to cast to Int within the query -  `set games = games - $1::int`. Will give you the answer since right about what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid decomposing objects outside of postgress and manipulate jsonb structure inside the query like this:

```
create table gameplayers as (select 1 as id, '[
{
    "game": "cyberpunk-2077",
    "status": "Backlog",
    "platform": "Any"
},
{
    "game": "new-pokemon-snap",
    "status": "Backlog",
    "platform": "Any"
},
{
    "game": "gameone",
    "status": "Backlog",
    "platform": "Any"
}
]'::jsonb games);



with
 ungroupped as (select * from gameplayers g, jsonb_to_recordset(g.games) 
  as (game text, status text, platform text)),
 filtered as (select id, 
     jsonb_agg(
      json_build_object('game', game, 
                        'status', status, 
                        'platfrom', platform
                       )
              ) games 
  from ungroupped where game not like 'cyberpunk-2077' group by id)     
UPDATE gameplayers as g set games=f.games 
       from filtered f where f.id=g.id;
```